# Pan sharpening of SPOT and Landsat images

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, pansharpening, worldview-2

Is there a way I can pansharpen SPOT and Landsat images? I have Panchromatic bands from QuickBird and WordlView-2 images and would want to pansharpen Landsat and SPOT, while still retaining features in my SPOT/Landsat images.

Yes - RGB composition

I have ENVI and ArcGIS.

Comment: What info do you use on the spot/landsat side ..a RGB composition?

Comment: What software is available to you to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Pan sharpening is a well documented image processing technique and you will find bunch of HowTo's  and tools in the web ([GDAL](http://blog.remotesensing.io/2013/04/pansharpening-using-a-handy-gdal-tool/), [ArcGIS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../009t/009t000000mz000000.htm), [Orfeo TB](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu25.html), [Grass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.fusion.brovey.html), [ENVI](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/SPEARPanSharpening.html)).

On a common data oriented processing approach using Geotiff for example, you can use open source software in 3 steps:

1. Synchronize the PAN and the RGB (or multichannel) stuff spatially which means, that both datasources (PAN and RGB) have to use the same coordinate system, same footprint and the same raster size. You can do his with the tools from the [GDAL biotop](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html) for example ([`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html), [`gdalwarp`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)).
2. [*One* way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansharpened_image) to do the sharpening step is, to transform the RGB colour space of the low resolution image into the [HSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colour space (aka IHS, HSV, HSB) and replace the intestity (I - channel) with the high resolution PAN data. If you stay in the GDAL biotop, the tool [`hsv_merge.py`](http://fwarmerdam.blogspot.de/2010/01/hsvmergepy.html) can do this job (step 3 too).
3. At least you have transform the resulting HSI image to back to RGB.

There are different ways "to inject" the hires image into the lowres RGB to get the [fused image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_fusion) (Brovey, PCA, etc.) with their [pro's and con's](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5473.pdf). If you are familar with `GDAL` library and a programming language like C or python you can find and adopt/apply programs like [`gdal_landsat_pansharp`](https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts) especially for landsat.